# Can birds touch their wing tips together either in front or behind (not above and below)?

Tags: zoology, ornithology, anatomy

Can the tips of a birds wings touch so that it would form a ring if view from above or below? I suspect it might be a bird of prey and at the moment it is picking something up from the ground but I can't find a good photo.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify your question. Are you asking if it's possible for a bird to touch its wings together, or are you asking for an identification of a species that you see doing this??

Answer (score 11):

[Black herons](https://www.audubon.org/news/watch-black-heron-fool-fish-turning-umbrella) (*Egretta ardesiaca*) can overlap their wing tips in front of them while doing what is known as canopy feeding.
[image: Black herons canopy feeding ("umbrella" posture).]

Comment: Oooo, just saw this! Great example!

Comment: Thanks! I think I knew some herons must do this because of ["canopy feeding" by the Reddish Egret](https://www.auduboneverglades.org/april-2018-bird-of-the-month-reddish-egret/) — happy new year!

Comment: Cool, I never knew that. Happy New Year to you, too!